# Using the difference quotient to find $f(x,y)=cos(xy)$

Tags: calculus

I find myself stuck on using the difference quotient when $y$ is a constant in the following function.

$f(x,y)=\cos(xy)$

this is what I did

$f(x,y)=\frac{\cos((x+h)y)-\cos(xy)}{h}$  as $h\rightarrow0$

then I did

$f(x,y)=\frac{\cos(xy+hy)-\cos(xy)}{h}$

but I find myself stuck on this part.

now i have

$f(x,y)=\frac{cos(xy)cos(xh)-sin(xy)sin(xh)-cos(xy)}{h}$

Comment: Did you mean (in the first line), $\cos(xy)$?

Comment: as h approaches zero I forgot to mention

Comment: yes cos(xy) is what I meant

Comment: @FernandoMartinez I took the comma out of the title too. Moreover, did you try the sum formula for cosine? that will "break apart" that $xy+hy$ term

Comment: Hint. You can use the identity $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$.

Comment: The idea is essentially the same as differentiating f(x)=cos(ax) from the limit definition, which you can find in any calc 1 book.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\cos u − \cos v = −2 \sin(\frac{u+v}{2}) \sin(\frac{u-v}{2})$.